# undefined method tag for Hash Using identity_cache and delayed_job

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml, delayed-job

I'm getting the error "undefined method `tag=' for #<Hash:0x007f9836dfdab0> when using identity_cache (v 0.0.4) and delayed_job (v 3.0.3) in the same app.

I followed the stack trace and found that delayed_job overwrites ActiveRecord::Base#encode_with. In the delayed_job version, it calls

```
coder.tag = ['!ruby/ActiveRecord', self.class.name].join(':')
```

It seems that ActiveRecord::Base expects coder to be a Hash, while delayed_job assumes it is a Psych::Coder, which does have a tag= method.

Finally, identity_cache does call encode_with, and passes a Hash. Hence the error.

I am using ruby 1.9.3p429, which has psych included as a stdlib. I am not specifying the yaml parser engine anywhere, and it always returns psych when I check (some people have complained about a similar problem, but they were using syck for yaml parsing).

So, I guess the question is, how do I make delayed_job play nice with identity_cache?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but the monkey patch below is a work around. So far I have not observed any errors. I dropped it in .../config/initializers/patch_identity_cache.rb:

```
module IdentityCache
  module ConfigurationDSL
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      alias_method :original_build_normalized_has_many_cache, :build_normalized_has_many_cache
      def build_normalized_has_many_cache(association, options)
        original_build_normalized_has_many_cache(association, options)

        self.class_eval(ruby = <<-CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__)

          def #{options[:population_method_name]}
            @#{options[:ids_variable_name]} = #{options[:ids_name]}
            association_cache.delete(:#{association})
            @#{options[:records_variable_name]} = nil
          end

        CODE
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

pduey's answer didn't work for me since IdentityCache code changed since his answer.

The following fix from [this issue](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/435) works for identity_cache 0.2.3:

```
# config/initializers/patch_identity_cache.rb:
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def encode_with_override_override(coder)
    encode_with_without_override(coder)
    coder.tag = "!ruby/ActiveRecord:#{self.class.name}" unless coder.is_a? ::Hash
  end
  alias_method :encode_with, :encode_with_override_override
end
```